# What's the easiest way to deploy an ASP.NET MVC 3 project to Windows Server 2003?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, deployment, .net-4.0, windows-server-2003

Is there some kind of deployment wizard I can run and have it install just the things it needs to run right onto the server end point? Do I have to build the project using VS2010 on the server? If I can't get this thing deployed today I am really going to be screwed.

IIS 6 is there and I think .NET 4 is installed (I tried installing it from Microsoft and they had me install a million things like VS2010 express and SQL Server and all this other crap, the install failed but .NET 4 does show up in IIS).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I achieved this by enabling an FTP site for the IIS server website and using this to deploy the web application within visual studio 2010 which will build and deploy just the changed files for each build. Works very well. You can even add a Publish toolbar to help deploy regularly more easily.

Comment: this turned out to be easiest, already had Filezilla Server running so I just made a user for the VS project, next I may switch to using SVN though, deploy my project to a local folder, commit it, and then check it out on the server

Comment: I enabled IIS FTP server which is easy to create an FTP site per IIS website easily. I also use SVN for backup but this is to another server drive that is backed up automatically every week. Note that SVN commits are funny file formats for compression and will not work for deploying a website via SVN directly onto your web server.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is install the .NET Framework 4.0 (32 / 64 depending on build) and run aspnet_regiis.exe in the Framework folder.

For me this is located here:

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe

Hope this helps!

You can also use the publish command from VS 2010 to save it to the filesystem and then copy the files into an IIS site on the target server. Just map a network drive to X: or something (for your sites root) and publish directly to the share.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at [Web Deployment projects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd483479.aspx) or even the VS "[Publish](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/29/vs-2010-web-deployment.aspx)" feature

Answer (score 0):

From the Build menu in VS2010, just click Publish [name of your web project] and enter the location on your web server where the site is going to be hosted.

VS2010 will publish the files required there.

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't be necessary to install VS2010 Express, just to deploy a site. But if .Net 4 and ASP.NET MVC 3 is installed, you should be able to deploy. Right click the web app in VS2010, and hit Publish.

Remember to set the configuration to Release!

But, with IIS 6 you could be in for a fight in regard to HTTP Modules, Handlers and other server configuration. Anything inside your `Web.config`'s `system.webServer` section will always be ignored by IIS 6.